# What determines the location of the 'pathdef.m' file on Windows?

Tags: windows, matlab, configuration-files

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5YQCPR/index.html?product=ML says:

> By default, the 'pathdef.m' file may be located in either the
>   '$MATLABROOT/toolbox/local' directory or the '$USERPATH' directory,
>   where $MATLABROOT and $USERPATH are the directories displayed after
>   entering the commands matlabroot (e.g. C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b) and userpath (e.g. C:\Users\francky\Documents\MATLAB)

So, what determines the location of the `pathdef.m` file on Windows (`matlabroot` vs. `userpath`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html):

> By default, `pathdef.m` is in `matlabroot/toolbox/local`.

However, there is apparently more to it than that.

If we add `matlabpath` to the top of `matlabrc.m`, it will tell use the search path *before* it has even "set up" the search path:

```
        MATLABPATH

    C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\local
>>
```

So the only thing on the path is `matlabroot/toolbox/local` and that's where MATLAB will find `pathdef.m` by default.  Right?  I thought so, but a simple test with a `pathdef.m` in `userpath` proved that in fact `userpath` was the first priority for `pathdef.m`.  Why?  Because in MATLAB, **the working directory takes priority over anything on the `matlabpath`**, and the startup folder is determined by `userpath`!

There are [multiple ways to specify the startup working directory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/changing-the-startup-folder.html), with and without the use of `userpath`'s functional form. I just verified that changing the "Start in:" property of the Windows shortcut will prevent the `pathdef.m` in the default `userpath` from running.  You can achieve the same change in startup folder with the `userpath(path)` syntax, but then what would be the difference between the startup path and `userpath` unless you use the shortcut "Start in:" method?

To add to the confusion, the last line of the default `pathdef.m` under `matlabroot/toolbox/local` is `p = [userpath,p];`, so after `matlabrc.m` adds this to the path on startup, MATLAB will then give `userpath` precedence over `matlabroot`, *if* ther is a `pathdef.m` under `userpath`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting! I wonder whether the first page you linked to (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html) has being updated properly: on one of my machines, MATLAB 2013a had put the `pathdef.m` in `userpath`. Since `userpath` is the same for MATLAB 2013a and 2013b (and probably earlier versions), when I installed MATLAB 2013b along with MATLAB 2013a, MATLAB 2013b was reading the 2013a `pathdef.m`. Anyway, that's good to know, the takeaway for me is to make sure nothing version-specific lies in userpath.

  `pathdef.m` `userpath`

Comment: In case it clarifies any confusion (perhaps not), the "Start in" property of the Windows shortcut is equivalent to using the `-sd` option to the `matlab` command.

Comment: @SamRoberts It would except that it has unfortunately been deprecated, at least in Windows, so don't count on it to keep working.